# \xe8 matching \xf1 in str_detect() and str_replace_all()

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, gsub, stringr

I want to process text files including some characters shown in hexadecimals on R. When I tried to convert those back into more readable characters, I encountered some unexpected (to me) behaviours of `stringr` functions. Specifically, `\xe8` apparently matches `\xf1`:

```
library("tidyverse")
str <- "ni\xf1a"
str_detect(str, "\xe8") # [1] TRUE
```

This is inconvenient when I want to convert `\xe8` into `è` and `\xf1` into `ñ` in the same files:

```
> str %>% 
+   str_replace_all("\xe8", "è") %>% 
+   str_replace_all("\xf1", "ñ")
[1] "nièa" # I expect niña
```

Interestingly, `gsub()` works as I expect:

```
> str %>% 
+   gsub("\xe8", "è", .) %>% 
+   gsub("\xf1", "ñ", .)
[1] "niña"
```

1. Why does `\xe8` match `\xf1` in `str_detect()` and `str_replace_all()`? Is there a way to avoid it?
2. Why is the behaviour different between `stringr` functions and `gsub()`?

#### Update

Here is part of the output of `devtools::session_info()`:

```
> devtools::session_info()
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
 os       macOS Catalina 10.15.7      
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_GB.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2020-09-30                  

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date       lib source     
...
stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
...
```

Comment: It must be related to ICU vs PCRE

Comment: What OS are you on? What version of stringr are you using? What version of R? I can't replicate this result using Windows R 4.0.2 stringr_1.4.0

Comment: That's interesting. I'm similarly using R 4.0.2 stringr_1.4.0 but on Mac. Since the regular expression is partly locale-dependent, could that be an issue? I have added (part of) the output of `devtools::session_info()` in my post.

Comment: This occurs on my Mac but not my Windows machine. Doesn't appear to be a locale issue as the result doesn't change. 
`map_lgl(stringi::stri_locale_list(), function(x) {stringi::stri_locale_set(x); str_detect("ni\xf1a", '\xe8')})`. Using `fixed` matches correctly `str_detect(str, fixed("\xe8"))`

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to `fixed()`. I should of course have tested it! It's also interesting that the issue is indeed OS-dependent, which I hadn't thought about.

Comment: This seems to only be a thing with ICU - TRE and PCRE don't have this issue

Comment: might be a good idea to post this as a bug on ICU and/or stringr